# Counter-intuitive result for conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The following is probably simple, but somehow I don't see where my logic takes a wrong turn.
Let's assume that Sarah has lunch (L) today with 0.9. If (and only if) she has lunch, she will independently choose Avocado (A) with 0.9, Beef (B) with 0.9 and/or Celery (C) with 0.5 (multiple choices allowed). To me, this looks like follows:

$P (A \mid L) = 0.9$
$P (B \mid L) = 0.9$
$P (C \mid L) = 0.5$

The (a priori?) likelihood of her having lunch and the respective dish today would therefore be:

$P (A\cap L)= 0.9 \cdot 0.9 = 0.81$
$P (B\cap L)= 0.9 \cdot 0.9 = 0.81$
$P (C\cap L)= 0.9 \cdot 0.5 = 0.45$

Based on these results, how high is the probability that she will not eat any of these dishes today?

$(1 - 0.81) * (1 - 0.81) * (1 - 0.45) = 0.019855$

The opposite scenario, meaning that she will eat at least one of these dishes, could be:

$1 - 0.019855 = 0.980145$

Which is most likely wrong, as the probability of her having at least one of the dishes is higher than the probability of her having lunch (0.9).

I'd be glad if anyone could point me to the mistake in this calculation. Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: Those events are not independent, so you can not multiply the probabilities as you have done.

Comment: Suggestion: split into cases.  There are two ways in which she might eat none of those things.  A.  She skips lunch.  B. She has lunch, but chooses none of those items.  These cases are mutually exclusive so you can just add the probabilities.

Comment: Thanks, your suggested result makes sense (0.8928). What I don't get, though, is why the events are not independent. Do you mean that the probability that she'll have Beef depends on the probability that she'll have Celery (i.e. 0.81 depends on 0.45)?

Comment: They are dependent because both are linked to "having lunch".  That is, they are two events which may have a common cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is independent is her choice of the dishes **given** that she eats lunch, and not the general probability of getting each dish.

The formula is

$P = 0.1 + 0.9 \cdot((1 - 0.9)\cdot(1 - 0.9)\cdot( 1 - 0.5))$

This is the probability of not getting lunch, plus the probability of getting lunch and not choosing any of the three dishes.

Comment: Thanks also to you!